# Is it possible to create a Service Application backup using Central Administration on a different server

Tags: error, central-administration, backup

Is it possible to create a Service Application backup using Central Administration on a server that is not running Central Administration?

Let's say I have a SharePoint farm consisting of 3 servers:

- Application Server (Central Administration)
- Web Server
- Database Server

Can I navigate to the Central Administration site using the Web Server and create a Service Application backup on a local drive there?

Or can I only use Central Administration to create a Service Application backup on the server hosting Central Administration (Application server)

Running a service application backup using the Application Server, hosting Central Administration works, but running the same backup on the Web server fails mentioning a permission issue:

> "Directory does not exist or the SQL Server Service Account and the
>   logged-on user account do not have permission to read or write to the
>   backup folder. Specify a different directory or ensure that the
>   SharePoint Timer service and Microsoft SQL Server service accounts
>   have Full Control permission on both the file share and the underlying
>   folder."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from Central admin, You Cannot back up directly to tape. The backup location must be a UNC path or local drive. But

- if you have load balanced Central admin( means hosted on multiple servers, by default it is hosted on one server), then you can select either server.
- or create the UNC path and it will place the backup over their.

[Choose backup and recovery tools](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287880(v=office.12).aspx#section2)

Comment: What to you mean with back up directly to tape?